# Format Date in php and store in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this statement to save a date in mysql but I would it to save as an example:

`September 24, 2011, 6:39 am`.

Or should I have it and when I am retrieving it then I echo it like that?

```
try {
      $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        //insert into database with a prepared statement
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO admin (username, password, email, register_date, active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :register_date, :active)');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
            ':password' => $hashedpassword,
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':register_date' => $date,
            ':active' => $activasion
    ));
//else catch the exception and show the error.
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $error[] = $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: Side note: Please don't use the `>` character for personal formatting preferences; they're for a special purpose. I [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45334837/2) those out.

Comment: this is how I am calling the it from the table                               
   $nestedData[] = $row["register_date"];

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/* 
   * F --> for full month
   * D -->day
   * Y --> Year
   * H -->Hour
   * m -->minute
   * A -- PM or AM

*/
$date = date("F d, Y, H:m A");
echo $date;   
?>
```

Output will be

```
July 26, 2017, 21:07 PM
```

Comment: while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
 $nestedData=array(); 

 $register_date   = $row["register_date"];
 $register_date  = date("F d, Y, H:m A");

 $nestedData[] = $row["adminID"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["username"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["email"];
 $nestedData[] = $register_date;
 $nestedData[] = $row["login_date"];
 $nestedData[] = $row["active"];
 
 $data[] = $nestedData;
}                                                                                                                              it is just printing the same date for all the records

Comment: because you save `date` in the database in  a column type `date`  you should save `date` in a column type `varchar(50)`

Answer (score 0):

```
// original datetime string:
$str = 'September 24, 2011, 6:39 am';

$stmt->execute(array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username'],
        ':password' => $hashedpassword,
        ':email' => $_POST['email'],
        ':register_date' => strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", strtotime($str)),
        ':active' => $activasion
));
```

The date will be formatted as: `2011-09-24 06:39:00` and MySQL will be happy.

[**Live demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f6841fd63a20e347eff53b2a3bd48c52649efb82)

Docs: [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) | [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)